# How can I configure "HTTPS" schemes with the drf-yasg auto-generated swagger page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I know in a traditional swagger YAML file, we can define the schemes with:

```
schemes:
  - http
  - https

//OR

schemes: [http, https]
```

However, how can I do the same thing with auto-generated swagger page with the `drf-yasg` library?

Now, the generated swagger page only contains `HTTP` schemes, but `HTTPS` is missing. I've tried set the `DEFAULT_API_URL` in `setting.py` to `https://mybaseurl.com`, but it seems not to be working.

Comment: any progress on this? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a solution.

When defining get_schema_view() in `urls.py`, use this code:

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info( ... ),
    url='https://example.net/api/v1/', # Important bit
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,)
)
```

Note: You can either use https or http because of that better use this solution with an environment variable for different setups.

Comment: it work now for https, but what if I want to implement both http and htpps?

Answer (score 21):

To use both *http* and *https* schemes in swagger you can extend `OpenAPISchemaGenerator` from `drf_yasg.generators`.

```
class BothHttpAndHttpsSchemaGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
    def get_schema(self, request=None, public=False):
        schema = super().get_schema(request, public)
        schema.schemes = ["http", "https"]
        return schema
```

So now you can use it as `generator_class` for `get_schema_view()`

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info( ... ),
    public=True,
    generator_class=BothHttpAndHttpsSchemaGenerator, # Here
    permission_classes=(AllowAny,)
)
```

Comment: Adding on to this, you can use the `request` object to dynamically set the scheme:

```python
if request:
    schema.schemes = ["https"] if request.is_secure() else ["http"]

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
url='https://your_server_address/'
```

in the get_schema_view() function with a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to have `https` scheme in swagger page is to use `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` configuration.

Assuming that your Django REST API is sitting behind an **Nginx** that is doing SSL termination, you can let the Nginx forward `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` to your Django application (Nginx might already forward this header by default depending on how you set things up). With the configuration below, your Django application will realize that it is behind a SSL terminating Nginx, and Django's internal function `is_secure()` will return `True` when the header is present. [Refer to Django SSL Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header).

Once the `is_secure()` returns `True`, the swagger page scheme will automatically turn into `https`.

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

I like this approach since it does not require any hard coding url or even configuring url from environment variables. Additionally, the `is_secure()` function is used internally in other place as well so it is desirable to have the function work as it idealy should.