# base_url issues in drf_yasg swagger

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi, drf-yasg

I am running Django with Nginx in **8000** port. Here Nginx is exposed outside in 8000 port. But in Swagger UI the **base_url** is set as without port. So Swagger is trying to access endpoints without a port, then it gives a response as **TypeError: Failed to fetch**.

**Kindly refer to the below image to know how base_url is set**
[image]

**Kindly refer to the below image to know how a request is sent from Swagger**
[image]

When I access the endpoint (with port) using Postman it is working fine. The problem occurs only when I try using Swagger (because is sent a request without port).

Here I want Swagger to sent all the requests with the port. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Note:

1. I'm using the **drf-yasg==1.17.1** package to generate **Swagger UI**
2. Other requirements are **Django==3.0.3** and **djangorestframework==3.11.0**

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell the Nginx to forward the server port as well. As swager gets the base url port from request header (if not hardcoded as mtshaikh proposed).

eg. something like this this should be in Nginx config

```
location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8000/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clue. I found the right solution and added a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good solution but defining the complete `url` in the `get_schema_view()` in urls.py works!

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info( ... ),
    url='http://example.net:8080/', # Important bit
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,)
)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56090744/9137276)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @mtshaikh. It's working fine but is there any way to do this in an automatic way?

Comment: AFAIK, there is an [open issue/discussion](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/491) on this functionality currently going on at the `drf_yasg` github.

Comment: Little dirty, but it seems this is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Petr Synek for your answer

We need to tell the Nginx to forward the **http_host**.

```
location / {
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

This one resolved the above-mentioned issue

Answer (score 0):

[image]I personally think its something to do with Https or Http request, i ran into the same issue a couple of days ago and for me the simple solution was to change the scheme from http when making requests using my local set up and  to https ( on live server ) since i had installed ssl and only secure traffic was allowed.